# RDP farm automatic session reconnect

Tags: networking, rdp

We have a RDP farm with 100+ users who are using Windows 10. Sometimes we have network problems like short network outages and packet losses. When network problems occur users are disconnected from RDP session with error:

[image: Your Remote Desktop Services session has ended.]

However when I am logged on random server (not member of RDP farm) and network problems occur - I have window that says:

[image: The connection has been lost. Attempting to reconnect to your session...]

In connection properties of RDP when connecting to RDP farm the checkbox Reconnect if the connection is dropped is checked and grayed out:

[image: Reconnect if the connection is dropped]

Why RDP doesn't try to reconnect itself in RDP farm and looses connection immediately? Are there any settings that control this behavior? Sometimes users are forced to manually reconnect to RDP farm several times per hour if network is unstable. If there is no such setting may be there is at least timeout setting that I can configure for higher values so that RDP session survive short network outages?

Comment: Check group policy, Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Connections > Automatic Reconnection.

Comment: rsop.msc shows that this policy is not configured on both local computer and RDP server

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in wrong configuration of RDS collection. In collection properties > session there is an option "When a session limit is reached or a connection is broken > disconnect from the session > **Enable automatic reconnection**". This checkbox was cleared on my production farm.

[RDS Collection properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rElSt.png)